# '04 Ford Escape A/C is blowing ice cold air while driving but not idling

Tags: ford, ac, cooling-system, air

I own a 2004 Ford Escape V6 2wd, that has good R-134 refrigerate levels, blows ice cold air while driving or when A/C has been turned on while idling (ex. Like sitting in a parking lot) but once it's placed in park, doesn't get hot, but warm and kind of muggy. Or if it was blowing cold air in idling, will get hotter than the outside air (I live in Florida so its been about 90°F+ everyday with low 70°F at night). My A/C will also be hot if I've had cold air driving but stopped, shut off the engine for maybe 5 minutes and turned back on.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Your description is usually a sign the fan which deals with the A/C is not running. The fan(s) should turn on when the A/C compressor is running. If you're not hearing that, you'll need to investigate why. Could be the fan(s), relay, or wiring at fault.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to possible fan(s) issues, some vehicles use more than one speed - low, medium and high depending on ac pressures and coolant temperatures. Fans are always on when ac runs but won't if ac doesn't work (compressor isn't engaged). And unless you're familiar with refrigeration, a single gauge checking low side pressures means almost nothing. Refrigeration gauges are needed to assess whether or not a system is operating with the correct amount of refrigerant or if a leak occurred, releasing refrigerant and operating at less than ideal conditions.